# Where is DaggerApplicationComponent?

Tags: android, dependencies, dagger-2

In this site,
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android

I would like to make a dagger application component by referring to the site.

so i put build.gralde

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.35.1' // if you use the support libraries
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1'
```

but I can't find DaggerApplicationComponent and either DaggerAppComponent

just unresolved reference: daggerapplicationcomponent

How I can find it?

Please help anyone

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart android studio.
Please follow this link too https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304815/4785772

Comment: @Tausif Thanks. Finally I tried clean project and rebuild project, then make daggerapplicationcomponent